# Eclipse plugin "Run As" submenu disappearing

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have an eclipse plugin which configures a set of resources as a customized project and runs it. I have added run and debug choices to "Run As" and "Debug As" menus and also shortcuts in the tool bar. So when I put mouse over "Run As", I have two submenus:

- Run on Server
- My Customized project

I can click on "My customized project" and everything runs as desired.

However after I ran it once, I no longer have "My customized project" as a "Run As" submenus, it's gone. "Run on Server" is also gone and instead I have an "XSL Transformation" there.

I found a post with similar question here:
http://www.sigasi.com/content/run-menu-item-strangely-disappearing-context-menu

but his solution won't work for me. I already have the extension point defined.

Does anyone have an idea why this happens?

UPDATE:

I think I know where exactly the problem is but I still have no solution.

I have the following code when a customized project is finished running:

```
IJobManager manager = Job.getJobManager();
manager.addJobChangeListener(new JobChangeAdapter() {
  @Override
  public void done(final IJobChangeEvent event) {
    if (event.getJob().getName() == "Processing with selected modules" && event.getResult() == Status.OK_STATUS) {

      Display.getDefault().syncExec(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
          actionExport.setEnabled(true);
          try {
            PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage().showView("customized.output");
          } catch (CoreException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
          }
        }
      });
      manager.removeJobChangeListener(this);
    }
  }
});
```

the line `PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage().showView("customized.output");` is the source of the problem. I just want to switch to another view when the project finishes to show the result. There will be no problem with disappearing "Run As" submenu if I remove this line. But I want to show the view after running a project. Anyone has any clue about it?

Comment: An alternative is to click the Run button in the toolbar, your application should appear in the list there.

Comment: Hi Greg, thank you for reply. I have other ways to make the application appear again, but it's just bad user experience. I don't want to write in manual with something like "if this happens, do blabla..." I want to fix it from the beginning so that the application is always there in "Run As" menu. Any chance I can do that or it's a known bug?

Comment: Can you post your plugin.xml?

Comment: Hi Arye, it's a large file and I prefer not to pasting it here. Besides, you can't run it anyway. Have you ever experienced similar things?

Comment: updated post with more precise description of the problem.